# Mathematica takes too long to solve this

Tags: equation-solving, notebooks, trigonometry

I have the following system of equations:

```
x = -(1/3) + 4/3 Cos[1/3 π (-t1 - 2 t2)] Cos[1/3 π (-t1 + t2)] Cos [1/3 π (2 t1 + t2)]
y = 4/3 Sin[1/3 π (-t1 - 2 t2)] Sin[1/3 π (-t1 + t2)] Sin[1/3 π (2 t1 + t2)]
```

and I know that t1,t2 >= 0 and t1+t2<=1.

I wanted to ask *Mathematica* to give me `t1` and `t2` in terms of `x`, `y` - sort of inverse map the above function. so I did this:

```
Clear[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]];
Assuming[t1 >= 0 && t2 >= 0 && 
  t1 + t2 <= 
   1, {Solve[-(1/3) + 
      4/3 Cos[1/3 π (-t1 - 2 t2)] Cos[1/3 π (-t1 + t2)] Cos[
        1/3 π (2 t1 + t2)] == x && 
    4/3 Sin[1/3 π (-t1 - 2 t2)] Sin[1/3 π (-t1 + t2)] Sin[
       1/3 π (2 t1 + t2)] == y, {t1, t2}]}]
```

But it takes too long to solve, and keeps running.. I left it for half an hour and closed the kernel. Is something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
sol = Solve[{x == -(1/3) + 
    4/3 Cos[1/3 Pi (-t1 - 2 t2)] Cos[1/3 Pi (-t1 + t2)] Cos[
      1/3 Pi (2 t1 + t2)], 
  y == 4/3 Sin[1/3 Pi (-t1 - 2 t2)] Sin[1/3 Pi (-t1 + t2)] Sin[
     1/3 Pi (2 t1 + t2)]} // TrigToExp, {t1, 
 t2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

or

```
{a == Cos[1/3 Pi (-t1 - 2 t2)] Cos[1/3 Pi (-t1 + t2)] Cos[1/3 Pi (2 t1 + t2)], 
 b == Sin[1/3 Pi (-t1 - 2 t2)] Sin[1/3 Pi (-t1 + t2)] Sin[1/3 Pi (2 t1 + t2)]} /. 
{t1 -> 3 ArcTan[t1]/Pi, t2 -> 3 ArcTan[t2]/Pi} // Simplify // TrigExpand // FullSimplify
sol2 = Solve[%, {t1, t2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```